# ¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un archivo excel con Angular?

Tags: angular, excel

estoy iniciando con Angular y estoy desarrollando una web en la que debo leer el contenido de un archivo Excel y esto pasarlo a un tabla, he buscado algunos ejemplos sobre como leer el archivo pero no tengo nada en concreto, espero puedan ayudarme con algún ejemplo o sus comentarios, gracias

Comment: Empieza buscando una librería

Comment: Vale, pero alguna que me recomienden ?